# Xamarin iOS unable to get files from iCloud

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

```
        var uburl = NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetUrlForUbiquityContainer(null).Append("Documents", true);
        var path = uburl.Path;

        if (NSFileManager.DefaultManager.FileExists(path))
        {
            var enumurator = NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetEnumerator(path);

            var files = NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetDirectoryContent(path, out NSError err);

            NSObject file;
            while ((file = enumurator.NextObject()) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("yyy Yes iCloud! {0}", file);
            }

        }
```

GetUrlForUbiquityContainer returns path
uburl   {file:///Users/axcryptdev/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/638BD506-5514-41AD-B488-6C1FB23ACD57/data/Library/Mobile%20Documents/iCloud~net~axcrypt~axcrypt2~xamforms/Documents/} .

but GetDirectoryContent or GetEnumerator not returns any file paths.

I uploaded two files in iCloud but it didn't showing here.

Anyone face and fixed this kind of issue. Please help me.

Comment: Did you check for errors? Maybe you need to grant access before using iCloud.

Comment: I checked error and error is nil. Where I need to give access to use iCloud?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/enabling_cloudkit_in_your_app